# Using delegate after editing NSOutlineView item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

My setup is

I have nib file consisting of an NSpanel, with an NSOutlineView.

The outline view is populated via bindings and NSTreeController, I have the NSOutlineView subclassed where I have some delegate and drag and drop methods.

My Problem

I'm trying to implement the delegate method

```
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

I can edit any item in the NSOutlineview, once I hit "return" the delegate method is called, however the window is no longer active. And the item is left in "edit mode" I have to have to click an item above or below the edited item to terminate the edit mode.  I included a couple images to illustrate

Currently I don't have anything in the textdidendediting other than a NSlog to see if it was getting called.  If I remove the method it performs as expected, editing is completed, window is still active.

Editing item

[image: Editing item]

Once I hit "return" window loses focus and item is still in edit mode.

[image: Hit enter]

Comment: did you try calling -[super textDidEndEditing:]?

Comment: @KenAspeslagh That did it! If you change your comment to an answer I will accept it, also I would appreciate a quick explanation as to why you have to call super in this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If overriding the NSOutlineView's `textDidEndEditing:` is changing the tableview's behavior, try adding a call to `-[super textDidEndEditing:]`.

What's going on here is that `NSOutlineView` (or one of its super classes) is doing some important things in `textDidEndEditing:`, and by overriding that method in your child class, the parent class's method is never getting called.